# Unable to load asset image (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm repeatedly having the following exception in terminal while trying to add an asset image in the appBar of my Flutter application (running on an Android emulator):

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: /assets/images/small.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:675:14)
<asynchronous suspension>

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "/assets/images/small.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#64048(), name:
  "/assets/images/small.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 117 pixels on the right.

**This is the code of application's home:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gofundleaf/screens/profile.dart';
import 'package:gofundleaf/services/auth_service.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('/assets/images/small.png'),
                  const Text('leaf')
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _loading
            ? const CupertinoActivityIndicator()
            : ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Login'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    _loading = true;
                  });
                  final user = await AuthService.login();
                  if (user != null) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Profile(user: user),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      _loading = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The pubspec.yaml file is structured like this:

```
name: gofundleaf

description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
  http: ^0.13.4
  url_launcher: ^6.0.17

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

(The indentation is the same used in the actual file of my project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove / from your path that you are assigning to Image widget like

```
Image.asset('assets/images/small.png'),
```

Comment: Wow, this worked for me...  now the error is not showing...

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gofundleaf/screens/profile.dart';
import 'package:gofundleaf/services/auth_service.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/small.png'),
                  const Text('leaf')
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _loading
            ? const CupertinoActivityIndicator()
            : ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Login'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    _loading = true;
                  });
                  final user = await AuthService.login();
                  if (user != null) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Profile(user: user),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      _loading = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / slash in front of the assets/ path.
It should read `Image.asset('assets/images/small.png')`

Also, double check the image name, then save the file and hot restart.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image is declared in the asset section of your pubspec.yaml
[image]

every image that you want to be able to load should be declared,
if one is missing flutter wont be able to load it